# How to statistically describe the right answer of a multiple choice question?

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss, survey

Participants need to identify the right strategy of several storyboards through a multtiple choice questions (7 possible answers).

I collected 130 answers and now I want to show the significance that the participants identified the correct strategy (right answers in the multiple choice question) within the storyboard.

Accordingly, I thought using a one-sample chi-square nonparametric test to show the distribution of the "correct" answers, but I am not able to set the expected probability to zero for the other categories (e.g., correct answers 100%, other categories 0%).

Is there a more suitable test for my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Dichotomize your variable "correct" vs "not correct" responses. Pure blind chance of the "correct" is 1/7 and of the "not correct" is 6/7 in your case. Set these two quantities as the corresponding expected proportions in your one sample chi-sq test. Observe one-sided significance of the test. If in your sample the observed proportion of "correct" is greater than 1/7 and the p-value is significant, then people in population tend to select the correct answer more often than by blind chance.

Comment: Alternatively, use 1/7 as the expected value in a chi sq w 6 df.  (It might be that there is a second correct answer.)